# Statistics Question: Kernel Smoothing in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have data of this form:

```
 x    y
 1    0.19
 2    0.26 
 3    0.40
 4    0.58
 5    0.59
 6    1.24
 7    0.68
 8    0.60
 9    1.12
10    0.80
11    1.20
12    1.17
13    0.39
```

I'm currently plotting a kernel-smoothed density estimate of the x versus y using this code:

```
   smoothed = ksmooth( d$resi, d$score, bandwidth = 6 )
   plot( smoothed )
```

I simply want a plot of the x versus smoothed(y) values, which is ## Heading ##

However, the [documentation for ksmooth](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ksmooth.html) suggests that this isn't the best kernel-smoothing package available:

> This function is implemented purely
>   for compatibility with S, although it
>   is nowhere near as slow as the S
>   function. Better kernel smoothers are
>   available in other packages.

What other kernel smoothers are better and where can these smoothers be found?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you "simply want a plot of the x versus smoothed(y)", then I recommend considering  `loess` in package `stats` - it's simple, fast and effective. If instead you really want a regression based on kernel smoothing, then you could try `locpoly` in package `KernSmooth` or `npreg` in package `np`.

Comment: "Better kernel smoothers are available in other packages"...in what sense is locpoly better?